# When would I use "NotNullIfNotNull" on a property referencing itself?

Tags: c#, nullable, nullable-reference-types

In class `Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue`, there is a nullable value type property (`long?`) that is decorated with a `NotNullIfNotNull` attribute referencing itself (property `Length`).

```
[NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(Length))]
public long? Length { get; private set; }
```

What is the purpose of this attribute in the context of a value type and what is the difference to simply omitting the attribute declaration?

Comment: "A return value isn't null if the input argument for the specified parameter isn't null." https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705826/1043380

Comment: @gunr2171: In OP's example, their is no argument called `Length`. Likewise, the property *getter* might have a "return value", but the property itself doesn't. (And the property getter definitely has no argument - contrary to VB.NET, that is not supported in C#.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis): *A return value, property, or argument isn't null if the argument for the specified parameter isn't null.*

**The use-case scenario:**

*Sometimes the null state of a return value depends on the null state of one or more arguments. These methods will return a non-null value whenever certain arguments aren't null. To correctly annotate these methods, you use the NotNullIfNotNull attribute.*

Examples or code snippets can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis#conditional-post-conditions-notnullwhen-maybenullwhen-and-notnullifnotnull).

Comment: Thank you for the link, that page has a good summary of the different nullable attributes, but it does not answer my question. I know what a `NotNullIfNotNull ` attribute does in the context of nullable reference types and when referencing something else than the property it is declared on.

Comment: So the methods with the decorator, ENFORCE the non-nullity of the returned value. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this does not answer the question at all. There is no parameter called `Length` in OP's example, just a property. Likewise, regarding your "use-case scenario", there is no method in OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

I think I slowly get an idea what problem this declaration attempts to solve:

The property could write the value it receives to a different variable than the one that is returned (using a property like this)

```
[NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(Length))]
public long? Length {
    get { return _length }
    private set { _anotherLength = value }
}
```

or simply ignore the value in the setter or do some other strange things, the attribute is needed to tell the analyzer the value given to the setter *does indeed* set the variable returned in the getter.

Comment: The question remains when would I use the attribute on a nullable value type? Can I then omit the call to `Length.Value` and simply use `Length` instead?